# Can't find implementation of gtk_menu_shell_get_type (gtk)

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Can somebody tell me, how i can see implementation of **gtk_menu_shell_get_type** function and other common **..._get_type** functions in gtk3? According to this documentation [gtk+2.0-directfb](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/gtkplus-p2.0-directfb/2.0.9.2/gtkmenushell_8h.html) i can see implementation of this, but there is no any info about it in gtk3. I've downloaded its [one of the sources](https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk) and only can see:
1. gtkmenushell.h:
define GTK_TYPE_MENU_SHELL             (gtk_menu_shell_get_type ())
...
GDK_AVAILABLE_IN_ALL GType    gtk_menu_shell_get_type       (void) G_GNUC_CONST;
...
  2. gtktypefuncs.c:

*tp++ = gtk_menu_shell_get_type();

I've spent a few days with this problem and can't understand, how can i get the implementation of this function, to see it realization clearly.
In other sources I've met there's no any "c" file with this function, only header. How can i see implementation of it and others like this **..._get_type** function? Does anybody know this subtlety?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`gtk_menu_shell_get_type` function is defined in [gtkmenushell.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkmenushell.c#L163). It's not declared directly. Instead, macro [`G_DEFINE_ABSTRACT_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#G-DEFINE-ABSTRACT-TYPE-WITH-PRIVATE:CAPS) is used to declare it.

See example for [`G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#G-DEFINE-TYPE-EXTENDED:CAPS).

Comment: thanks a lot! I've studied types.h, gtypemodule.h,gtypemodule.c and understood what happens with this function. You've saved my time and my head from this problem. Thanks!